# Using Display Flex and Justify Content Space-Between, how to make it responsive?

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive, inline-styles

I currently have to have a container (called Card) with some text within it being space-between using justify-content and I want to make it responsive.

This is what it looks like normally in full screen.

[image]

And this is what it looks like when resizing the screen.

[image]

The card itself resizes and is responsive due to the `<div style={{ display: 'flex', 'justify-content': 'space-between', height: 48, width: 872, borderRadius: 0 }}>`.
Card is my own component however though it's just a a container.

I'm confused though on why my text to the right (Tokenized/Themed and Status) is not being flexed and responsive as I would of intended.

The text is still on the far right.

[image]

I'm really confused on how to fix this responsive issue I am having.

**This is my code**:

*(Note: removing the Card component will just remove the container and this is fine as it does not affect the flex or responsiveness)*

```
<Card hoverEffect={false} focusEffect={false}>
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', 'justify-content': 'space-between', height: 48, width: 872, borderRadius: 0 }}>

    <div 
      style={{ 
        'padding-left': '16px',
        'padding-top':'14px',
        'padding-bottom': '14px',
        'cursor': 'default',
       }}
     >
       Component Name
     </div>

     <div style={{ display: 'flex'  }}>

       <div 
         style={{ 
           'padding-right': '55px',
           'padding-top':'14px',
           'padding-bottom': '14px',
           'cursor': 'default',
           }}
         >
         Tokenized/Themed
       </div>

       <div
         style={{ 
           'padding-right': '40px',
           'padding-top':'14px',
           'padding-bottom': '14px',
           'cursor': 'default',
          }}
        >
          Status
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </Card>
```

I'm so confused on how to fix this and make the Tokenized/Themed and Status text to be responsive with the Card container.

Any and all help will be appreciated, thank you so much

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: The first rule of responsiveness is NOT using fixed pixel values

Comment: I use pixel values for the padding, width and height of the container. What should I be using instead?

Comment: If you want it responsive those pixel values will not change. You need to use a measure (`vh/vw/%`) that is linked to the width/height of the container/viewport.

Comment: Thank you in telling to use %. It's not entirely there yet but it's getting there now.

Comment: I would recommend using "min-height" instead of "height" and for the width you could give it "width: 100%;" and then set a max-width or min-width if necessary. Remember that "width: 100%;" is 100% of its parent, not the viewport. For that, use "width: 100vw;".